# Why does gprof tell me that a function that is called only once from main() is called 102 times?

Tags: c++, profiling, stack, call, gprof

I am a beginner, and wrote the following program for fun, to search through a directory and replace every occurrence of one word with another. I call the crt_ls_file() function once, and once only, but gprof tells me it is being called 102 times. I am wondering if anyone knows why this is. I have tried compiling the program will all and no optimizations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void crt_ls_file(const string& output_f, const string& dir);
void sed(const string& old_string, const string& new_string, const string& filename, const string& directory);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    string out_f;
    if  (argc <= 1) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Filename>" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        out_f =  ".sandr";
        crt_ls_file(out_f, string(argv[1]) );
    }

    ifstream out_fs( out_f.c_str() );
    string line;
    getline(out_fs, line);
    while( !out_fs.eof() ){
        sed(string("index_SYMBOL"), string("index1_SYMBOL"), line, string(argv[1]) );
        getline(out_fs, line);
    }
    out_fs.close();
    string f( "rm " + out_f );
    system ( f.c_str() );

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void crt_ls_file(const string& s, const string& a){
    ofstream ls( s.c_str() );
    ls.close();
    string ls_output( "ls -1 " + a + " > ./" + string(s) );
    system( ls_output.c_str() );
}

void sed(const string& o, const string& n, const string& f, const string& d){
    ofstream dummy(".temp");
    dummy.close();

    string sed_output( "sed 's/" + o + "/" + n + "/g' " + d + "/" + f + " > .temp" );
    system( sed_output.c_str() );
    string rp( "mv .temp " + d + "/" + f );
    system ( rp.c_str() );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system `gprof` shows only one call to `crt_ls_file` as it should be:

```
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  crt_ls_file(std::string const&, std::string const&)
```

So it seems you `gprof` is lying, which it sometimes does. If you really want to profile this program (there's little use), try callgrind and kcachegrind instead. They're much better and less arcane tools:

```
$ valgrind --tool=callgrind ./my_program some_dir
... let it do its job ...
$ kcachegrind
```